# sleep of death nexus 4

Tags: nexus-4, 5.1-lollipop

I have Nexus 4 with Android 5.1. Recently it started to get Sleep of Death occasionally. I think it started after updating Android from 4.* to 5.*. I read that it's bug in Android Lollipop and some advises to fix it for example to turn off wi-fi when phone sleeps. I tried, but it didn't help.

Some other advises: [one](http://creativeoptimist.blogspot.ca/2015/01/sleep-of-death-sod-problem-in-android.html), [two](http://www.reddit.com/r/nexus4/comments/2qsez5/anyone_getting_sleep_of_death_on_50/), [three](https://www.reddit.com/r/nexus4/comments/2u0q0l/possible_solution_to_sleep_of_death_issue/). I don't know which I should follow, it required a lot of time to try them all.

And I want to avoid rooting.

Comment: Well your "one" and "three" links don't seem to require more than a few seconds each to try, have you tried them?

Comment: for one: I didn't find Wake my Android Pro in Google Play.  three: wipe Google Play Services' data, does it mean clear cache?.

Comment: And maybe it takes several seconds to try but I should wait several hours or days to check if it has effect.

Comment: I assume it means clear cache, settings, and data. Several hours or days isn't a "lot of time" to wait to see if your phone behaves normally. You're going to have that phone for months or years anyways. Just try one of the solutions then go enjoy the weekend, get back to work next week, and if it happens again, try something else. Besides, no matter how you look at it, if the problem itself only happens once every few days, you're going to have to wait a few days no matter *what* solution you try. The fact is, the Sleep of Death doesn't have a single known cause, it's different for everybody.

Comment: okay, will try with Google Play. As I said I tried with wi-fi before and several days it was okay, I thought it was fixed, but then it started again.

Comment: If this issue still persists, then ultimately you may need to reflash the ROM (and even the kernel) and losing the data (still, you can backup the data first), but let's hope we don't need to do that. Meanwhile, try some that are mentioned on [this article](http://androgeek.com/5-android-errors-how-fix/) and [this](http://everydaylife.globalpost.com/can-stop-sleep-death-androids-37557.html). It seems there's no clear cause, so you have to try everything you can first.

Comment: @ Andrew, I did wiping Google Play Services' data couple weeks ago and didn't have SOD since. Hope it's fixed now.

Comment: just wrote that it's okay now and got this SOD again.

Comment: I wiped Google Play Services' data again and didn't have SOD for two week, got it again today. Should I wipe data every 2 weeks?

Answer (score 0):

I have used my Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 Charger and had success every time to wake up my phone from SOD. It takes around 5-10 min before you can see on the screen that it is charging. But a fast indication can be that the fixed red LED will start to flash and after a couple of minutes the screen will wake up and show that it is charging.

PS: I have discovered that both Samsung and LG phones are very picky when it comes to which charger you are using. Samsung and LG phones usually accept each other's charger but they will not accept unbranded ones or ones from other brands like Sony. So if you don't have a Samsung or LG charger go to your local store and buy one. I can't guarantee that it will work, but it does work on my phone.